# Rails Unit Test, Access to the DOM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

So I am writing a unit test for my rails application. I am trying to understand what StoreControllerTest has access to.

This is what the test looks like:

```
class StoreControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'h3', 'Agile Dev Book'
  end
end
```

This test is currently passing. So according to that fact, the StoreControllerTest has access to my routes for the controller? And it also has access to the DOM elements of the index page?

But it does not have access to our DB, which is why we have to create fixtures to use in our tests? However, even though it does not have access to our DB, the test file still knows that when we call something like `product.title` in our template, that it should look for the title attribute of one of our products in our yml file?

Just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: What makes you say it doesn't have access to the DB?

Comment: My thought is, that if it did have access to the DB, we wouldn't need to create fixtures as representations of our DB. Or maybe it does not have access to the contents of our DB, but has access to our tables and attributes?

Comment: Fixtures are test data that are loaded into the DB.

Comment: And then the data is deleted after the tests are run?

Comment: Basically yes. Specifics depend on how you've set up things